# Anne Frank Museum Amsterdam Tickets

Tags: netherlands, sightseeing, amsterdam

I was trying to book 2 tickets for the museum (24th or 25th July) but their website says all of them are booked. Even though there was more than 1 week left when I started checking. Can we get tickets on spot?

Is it possible that we go there and might be accommodated if someone who hasn’t bought the tickets didn’t show up or something? How many tickets do they have per day?

Comment: I have tried to get one single ticket for a visiting friend last summer, (visitor numbers low because of COVID) and not managed to find one. It is not impossible but you will need to keep looking or join the long queue if they allow 'no reservation' visitors in again.

Comment: Even before COVID, my experience is that it was typical for tickets to be booked weeks in advance during the summer. According to [the website](https://www.annefrank.org/en/museum/tickets/): "Tickets are not sold at the door, only online." They used to have a queue for visitors without reservations, but I imagine that's suspended due to the pandemic.

Comment: @ZachLipton You're correct - they just turn you down at the door if you don't have a reservation (note that even people with museumkaart need to book a reservation for all museums now)

Answer (score 5):

When visiting Amsterdam, The ideal time to purchase Anne Frank Museum tickets is close to two months before. This is because 80% of the daily tickets are released two months in advance at noon local time (CEST), and the other 20% are released on the day of at 9 am local time(CEST). To attempt to get one of the day of tickets you need to check the day of at 9 am local time(CEST) here https://www.annefrank.org/en/museum/tickets/.

If there is an opening be willing to take any available time slot. This could affect your itinerary but if this is a priority it's well worth it. You can also check throughout the day to see if a time opens up for the day of. Again be prepared to take any available time slot.

Comment: If you’re good with scripting languages you could also consider writing a bot that will snag a 9am ticket for you.

Comment: Is the information about 20% tickets being released at 9AM given somewhere officially?

Comment: You can find the percentage when tickets are available on sites such as the following https://www.dutchamsterdam.nl/82-anne-frank-house